# slideToggle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I would like a code review for my first simple slideToggle jQuery plugin.

[Demo](https://rawgithub.com/Shivambh28/ezToggle/master/demo.html)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ezToggle = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
                selector : '.yourSelector',
                speed :  300,
                openedClassName : 'opened',
                closedClassName : 'closed',
            }, 
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var originalHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);

                options.minHeight = options.minHeight || $(this).find(defaults.selector).outerHeight(true);

                if (!$(this).hasClass(defaults.openedClassName)) {
                    $(this).addClass(defaults.closedClassName).height(options.minHeight);
                }       

                $(this).find(defaults.selector).on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var $parent = $(this).parent();

                    if ( $parent.hasClass(defaults.closedClassName) ) {

                        $('.'+defaults.openedClassName)
                            .removeClass(defaults.openedClassName)
                            .addClass(defaults.closedClassName)
                            .animate( {
                                height : options.minHeight
                            }, defaults.speed );

                        $parent.removeClass(defaults.closedClassName)
                               .addClass(defaults.openedClassName)
                               .animate({
                                   height : originalHeight
                               }, defaults.speed);

                    } else if ( $parent.hasClass(defaults.openedClassName) ) {

                        $parent.removeClass(defaults.openedClassName)
                               .addClass(defaults.closedClassName)
                               .animate({
                                   height : options.minHeight
                               }, defaults.speed);

                    }
                });

            });

    };
}) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't know already, this type of plugin is referred to as an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). I would suggest reading the code for the jQuery plugin (since you are using jQuery) to find out how they do it. With this you can get ideas, see their organization, and if you find something that can be fixed/improved you'll have the power to contribute!

To add to redexp's answer about the `preventDefault()` method.
In your click functions you might want to prevent the default browser action on a link, which is to direct the page to that link. Since you just want to perform something on your page and don't actually want the browser to leave the page you should prevent that action. The difference between the two is that `return false;` does that and at the same time stops event propagation. Propagation being when you click on an element, it triggers an event on the element, and any events on its parent elements (because technically they were also clicked). Whether or not you need to stop propagation is up to you, so pick accordingly.

So basically:

```
function() {
  return false;
}

// Is the same as doing

function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

It's all probably a lot more complicated than this and articles [like this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) probably explain it all a lot better.

As you progress in plugin development you should start to think about implementing design patterns. There are almost endless options of patterns you can use and some you can event make sort of a hybrid pattern. Don't feel overwhelmed with all the options pick out a couple to start with and try them out. I'd suggest the [Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) ([another good article](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/)) since you've already sort of implemented it in this plugin. Also look at the Observer Pattern (aka Pub/Sub) it's great for dealing with custom events. [This video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/custom-events-and-the-observer-pattern/) by Jeffery Way does a great job of explaining the concept. I'd recommend you'd watch the rest of the episodes from that series as well because he does cover some good ground on plugins.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need `defaults` and second `options` can be undefined so

```js
options = $.extend({
        selector : '.yourSelector',
        speed :  300,
        openedClassName : 'opened',
        closedClassName : 'closed',
    }, options || {});
```

Third don't use every time `$(this)`, define it once and use everywhere

```
var $this = $(this);

var originalHeight = $this.outerHeight(true);
...
```

Next, instead of `e.preventDefault();` just `return false` in the end of `.on('click', function(e) {`